# Cast a squeryl Query to a case class scala

Tags: scala, casting, squeryl

I am new to Squeryl and trying to figure out how to cast the results I get back from a query into case class. I have something like this

```
def getUsers = {
    val data = getUserData
    ...
}

def getUserData = {
    transaction {
        from(users)(s =>
            select(s.id, s.firstName, s.lastName, s.userName, s.email, s.lastLoginDate, s.dateJoined)
        )
    }
}

case class UserData(userId: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, userName: String, email: String, lastLoginDate: Timestamp, dateJoined: Timestamp)

case class UserDataRecords(users: List[UserData])
```

Ideally, I would like to get the data back in the from of UserDataRecords. Right now it is returned as Query[Tuple7]. Such as

```
... 
(5,Suzie,Queue,squeue,SQueue@example.com,2014-01-15 22:02:12.0,2014-01-15 22:02:12.0)
...
```

What I cant figure out is how to cast this data. Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `map` to transform the result list. Something like the example below should be a starting point:

```
def getUserData = {
    transaction {
        from(users)(s =>
            select(s.id, s.firstName, s.lastName, s.userName, s.email, s.lastLoginDate, s.dateJoined)
        ).toList.map { row =>
            UserData(row._1, row._2, row._3, row._4, row._5, row._6, row._7)
        }
    }
}
```

This will iterate through each row and create a `UserData` object out of the tuple, leaving you with `List[UserData]`.

That said, if your schema `users` is of type `Table[UserData]`, then you could simply do:

```
from(users)(s => select(s))
```